# whats means #XXX_ID# in Insert and what DB could it be?

Tags: sql, insert

I have a .sql file and doesn't know for what DB it is.
It contains inserts with some #XID# values.

Are these some sort of bind parameters like :XXX_ID in oracle?

The lines in the .sql file looks like the following:

```
INSERT INTO 'Tab1' ('XXX_ID','s1','s2') VALUES (#XXX_ID#, 'xbd', '1');
INSERT INTO 'Tab1' ('XXX_ID','s1','s2') VALUES (#XXX_ID#, 'xbd', '2');
```

Comment: Are you using any ORM framework?

Comment: I dont't know for what it is. I got only these .sql files and have to port it to mysql.